# Accessing LogedIn user Id in facebook Page?

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Here I am Using Signed Request in facebook :

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Here As per document in json object contain following field :

**"user", 
"algorithm",
"issued_at",
"user_id",
"oauth_token",
"expires",
"app_data",
"page",
profile_id**

In my code here I am getting json object successfully but I missed "**user_id**" their is something I have missed here ?????

Thanks for suggestion..

Comment: Hi Yashwant did you find answer?

Answer (score 0):

On the Facebook documentation page you linked to, it says:

"If the **user has not authorized** your application, your application will only be passed a **subset of the above information**."